# How to send data over 2 connected Bluetooth devices

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am creating an application that uses the system Bluetooth manager to connect 2 devices. Is it possible to send data programmatically through an app?
(I understand that you need to use a BluetoothSocket to get the input and output streams. How to I get the socket for the connected devices? )

Answer (score 1):

[This sample project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat) explains how to send data between 2 devices. If you examine `BluetoothChatService` class you will get all the details you need. It's not that hard. Opening sockets and moving data from worker thread to UI is explained clearly. `ConnectedThread` is sending data to UI thread